# Align divs with different heights using css

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Hi I want to align two rows of div under each other no matter the height of the divs in the row above. I'm using `display:inline-block;` so that the divs will inline next to each other.

Here is what I'm getting

[Photo 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hl4VU.png)

Notice that div #2 is slightly shorter than div one

and here is what i want to accomplish

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOWP9.png)

Notice that in the second picture no matter the height of the div above it the second row still aligns as it should.

here is my css

```
.post-set{
max-width:445px;
margin:0px 1px 15px 0px;
padding:0;
display:inline-block;
border-bottom:1px solid #e1e1e1;
vertical-align:top;
}
```

i'm using this in my wordpress theme. Here is the html along with the php.

```
<div class="medium-8 column post-set" style="padding:0;">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf(__( 'Read %s', 'wpbx' ), wp_specialchars(get_the_title(), 1)) ?>">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('fifth-post'); ?>
                </a>
          <div class="row column" style="padding:0">
              <h1 class="fifth-post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><h1>
<div class="fifth-ex">
<?php echo excerpt(18); ?>
</div>

<span class="fifth-by-line"> BY: <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></span>
</div>
</div>
```

You can visit **GetVersed.us** to see a live example. It's the section under the "Get Your Voice Heard Banner"

is there a way to accomplish this without suggesting masonry?

Comment: I would deploy all divs within a table, each row of the table having a pair of divs (in your example, the first row having divs 1 and 2 while the second divs 3 and 4).

Comment: @FDavidov I'm not sure I understand what you mean. do i need to `display:table;`

Comment: post your html or recreate in codepen?

Comment: I'll post an answer with sample HTML.

Comment: Any other solutions? Preferably css

Comment: without suggesting masonry .... could you provide the parernt div or outer sturcture of div with **.post-set** ?

Answer (score 3):

I don't see HTML you are using. But here is solution with my html code and yours CSS class. Notice that in CSS I set *width* instead of max-width.

Different height of div blocks I set using inline style. It can be set in class or auto.

```css
.post-set{
  width:60px;
  margin:0px 1px 15px 0px;
  padding:0;
  display:inline-block;
  border-bottom:1px solid #e1e1e1;
  vertical-align:top;
  background-color:black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="post-set" style="height:20px;">
    
  </div>
  <div class="post-set" style="height:35px;">

  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="post-set" style="height:15px;">


  </div>
  <div class="post-set" style="height:30px;">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple table and place your divs as follows:

```
 <table>
     <tbody>
         <tr>
             <td>
                <div 1...>
             </td>
             <td>
                <div 2...>
             </td>
         </tr>   
         <tr>
             <td>
                <div 3...>
             </td>
             <td>
                <div 4...>
             </td>
         </tr>   
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This will make sure that the alignment is as you wish. You can then add some styles if you wish.

Comment: Using tables to achieve a desired alignment is quite common. You can even check Facebook's username and password (Web version) at the top banner... Also a table arrangement.

Comment: So use tables instead of css and divs? @FDavidov

Comment: Yes. Use a table (as schematically proposed in my answer) and deploy your divs within the cells of the table. This will resolve your alignment problem. If you need additional **formatting** (like borders, background, etc.), then you can user css.

Comment: But with php it will automatically repeat the first row and table. It will give me one row and one table over and over

Comment: I'm afraid that your issue is not well defined. You were talking about arranging 4 divs in pairs, not an unknown number of pairs. If that is the situation, you could repeat the `<tr>` parts and not the table, right?

Comment: is it possible to use `nth-child:before` with `content:"<tr>";` @fdavidov

Comment: I'm not an expert on php. I can tell you how to do things with AngularJS though, but it would mean to change your framework. Best would be to check how to cause a table record repeat with php. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

HTML:

```
<div class="item_container">
  <div class="item">

  </div>
  <div class="item">

  </div>
</div>
<div class="item_container">
  <div class="item">


  </div>
  <div class="item">

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.item_container {
  display:flex; align-items:stretch;
}
.item { float:left; }
```

Comment: I have already coded the entire site with foundation lol and flexbox doesn't work well for me